# youtube player api. If the VIDEO_ID contains a special symbol, it is not working

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I try play video.
there are two youtube videos.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieNDZQosCNk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6HX9m_ileY&t=28s

[ieNDZQosCNk] is OK.

but [G6HX9m_ileY&t=28s] is not working.

If the `VIDEO_ID` contains a special character, it will not play.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Define *not working*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you've selected the wrong `VIDEO_ID`.

You included the parameter `t`!

The actual video ID is `G6HX9m_ileY`.

The `&` in the simple shows us that there is another parameter, `t=28s`.